# Alternative of this script in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following script to get the content of the `remaining.php`.

The drawback is that sometimes it doesn't work or it is kinda slow to display the text. Is there any other way of doing this ?

Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#SubmitButton").click(function (){
        $('#remaining').load('remaining.php');
    });
});
```

Comment: You will need to quantify "kinda slow." Is the server slow to respond? Can remain.php be optimized? Is the slowness on the client side? If so, under what conditions? When you have answered these questions, you will be well on your way to identifying the best solution.

Comment: When you run your debugger, does the delay occur when performing http request?  JQuery may not be the problem.

Comment: @asotshia: You should use some 'developer tools' of your browsers to check out requests. I'm pretty sure you will find out that it is the request that makes it 'slow'.

Answer (score 1):

If "sometimes it doesn't work or it is kinda slow", the problem is probably the server you are using, not your javascript code.

The javascript code you're showing us here doesn't really do anything that could be slow, it only binds an event on a submit button. However, what *could* be slow is waiting for the answer from your web server when sending a request for remaining.php

From there, there is a thousand of reasons why your web server could be slow. Maybe you could post the content of your remaining.php file so we can see what is going on in there.

Comment: Will you improve your answer by explaining the reasoning behind your assumption?

Answer (score 1):

You could directly include the contents of `remaining.php` into the initial markup but make it hidden by applying `display:none;` style to the #remaining element. Then when the button is clicked simply show it:

```
$(function() {
    $('#SubmitButton').click(function () {
        $('#remaining').show();
    });
});
```

Of course if you need to pass some parameters to the script which will depend on some javascript variables that are known only at the moment the button is clicked you will need to use AJAX as you are currently doing.

Comment: Thanks but the content of remaining.php is changing when #submitbutton is clicked

Comment: I think the goal here is to avoid loading the content of remaining.php unless it's necessary. In my opinion, this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @asotshia, oh then you should use AJAX. Your client side code is fine. If you are experiencing some *slowness* you will have to look at your server side code or your network connection speed.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a fault of jQuery, but the speed of return from your server. Perhaps there's a better way to handle it instead of fetching a full page?

For example, if your content request was only retrieving a message, you could return JSON from your server and have jQuery handle the data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#SubmitButton").click(function (){
        $.post('remaining.php',
               null,
               function(data) {
                   // do stuff with your JSON result
               });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), you're sending a request to the server to get your content, which is why it can seem slow. I'm not sure why it sometimes won't work , but I would venture to guess that you may be clicking $("#SubmitButton") before $(document).ready fires.

Depending on your implementation, you may be able to refactor your application so that the text you want to display is pre-loaded on the page.